# callbyname works with array element as procname

Tags: arrays, vba, callbyname

I have a terrible problem. I built up monstrous classes with many properties, among which there are array properties as well.

if I would like to refer to these with CALLBYNAME, it wont work, let us see an example:

```
public sub whatsoever()

    Dim alfaarray() As Variant

    Dim g As Integer

    Dim obj As Object

    ReDim alfaarray(4)

    Set obj = New teszt

    For g = 0 To 4
    alfaarray(g) = "g" & CStr(g)
    Next g

    Call obj.init

    CallByName obj, "GARG", VbLet, alfaarray

end sub
```

class: `teszt`

```
Dim pgarg() As String

Property Let GARG(index As Long, value As String)
pgarg(index) = value
End Property

Property Get GARG(index As Long) As String
GARG = pgarg(index)
End Property

Public Sub init()
    ReDim pgarg(4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear MAts, thanks a lot, I wasnt clear: Id like to add an array to an array property which is yet empty and for this purpose Id like to use callbyname. so I only need vblet, i wont run any sub :) anyway, I searched it everywhere, there is no solution so far and maybe there is no solution at all. again we are at the limits of vba :(

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem; deleted my previous comment. This is the new one: If what you want to do doesn't work with the built-in `CallByName` you need to write your own one that works around the limitations. There you can loop over the array and explicitly call your properties one by one for each entry.

Comment: You have to use typelib as mentioned here http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?405366-RESOLVED-Using-CallByName-with-variable-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Your `GARG` property Let accepts an index and a string: you can't pass in a whole array instead

```
Public Sub whatsoever()

    Dim g As Long
    Dim obj As Object

    Set obj = New teszt
    obj.init

    For g = 0 To 4
        CallByName obj, "GARG", VbLet, g, "g_" & CStr(g)
    Next g

    Debug.Print obj.GARG(0) '>> g_0
    Debug.Print obj.GARG(1) '>> g_1

End Sub
```